# get json specific value in javascript from json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json.json file like this

```
{"name1":"Hallo","name2":"Defy","name3":"Carm","name4":"Disney"}
```

And this script im using to read the file

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$.getJSON("json.json", function(person){
$.each(person, function(key, value)
{document.write(key+"= "+value+"<br />"); 
});
});
});
</script>
```

This script is made to poin out all of the data but i need only "name3" value to be stored to +value+

How to do that?

Comment: Never use `document.write` from an asynchronous callback (and even less, explicitly after `window.load`)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to iterate then:

```
$.getJSON("json.json", function(person){
    document.write("name3=" person.name3);
});
```

I'd probably stray away from `document.write` and append to a container.

```
<div id="test"></div>

$.getJSON("json.json", function(person) {
    $("#test").append("<span> name3= " + person.name3 + </span>");
});
```

Comment: this is ok but wath if the "name3" is now "name-3" ??

Comment: @user3329634  You can do `person["name-3"]`

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` provides the JavaScript object that is represented by the JSON it retrieves.

To access the `name3` property of the object, as with any JavaScript Object, you can simply do:

```
$.getJSON("json.json", function(person){
    // do whatever you want with person.name3...
    console.log(person.name3);
}
```

Comment: this is ok but wath if the "name3" is now "name-3" ??

Answer (score 0):

To access to the property you just have to use " . ", so to get the name3 you have to do value.name3

There's no no need to use a foreach if you only have 1 item

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $.getJSON("json.json", function(person){
            document.write(key + " = " + value.name3 + "<br />"); 
        });
    });
</script>
```